# JCheckBox with square border

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jcheckbox

The default `JCheckBox` borders in Mac OS are rounded, but I need a **square** as checkbox.
Is there a way to accomplish this task **without using an `ImageIcon`**?
In other words, I need some examples of Java classes that implement good-looking square-checkboxes (something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQmFZ.png)).

Comment: You could create your own, using an `AbstractButton` and `ButtonModel`

Comment: `JCheckBox` is a `JToggleButton` which is toggling an image whenever it's being selected. So as **MadProgrammer** expressed, you can have your square images for both *selected* and *un-selected* states and implement it by yourself easily.

Comment: The simplest solution I found (in 5 seconds of testing) was to use `JCheckBox#setIcon` and `JCheckBoc#setSelectedIcon` and pass it two different `Icon`s (I just create a couple of `BufferedImage`s filled with different colors), so, if you opposed to a solution which might take 10 lines of code, the only other solution you have is to make your own button and render it the way you want...

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you provide me a concrete example please? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Yoghi I provided two

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just saw it. thanks :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said *"without using an ImageIcon"* - but, it's the simplest solution which doesn't require a lot of mucking about and can easily produce (unselected/selected) quickly and easily

[image: Unselected][image: Selected]

```
public class ColorCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

    public ColorCheckBox(Color unselectedColor, Color selectedColor) {
        setSelectedIcon(icon(Color.MAGENTA));
        setIcon(icon(Color.WHITE));
    }

    protected Icon icon(Color filled) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(25, 25, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(filled);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
        g2d.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

}
```

> But I said ...

Why is everyone so hell bent on not using the simplest solution available to them.

In that case, the next simplest solution might be to simply override the `paintComponent` method and paint over what ever the UI delegate is painting...

```
public class ColorCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

    private Color unselectedColor;
    private Color selectedColor;

    public ColorCheckBox(Color unselectedColor, Color selectedColor) {
        this.unselectedColor = unselectedColor;
        this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        if (isSelected()) {
            g.setColor(selectedColor);
        } else {
            g.setColor(unselectedColor);
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

}
```